# How to implement Graphical password method to store passwords for an application

Tags: passwords

I am trying to build an authentication system which uses graphical password method to store passwords. Please tell me how can i implement this graphical password method to store passwords.

Thanking you..

Comment: Question is too vague, please clarify with a lot more detail.

Comment: hi, in one of my application instead of remembering alphnumeric passwords i am planning to implement this graphical password method(like we unlock our android phones) so that user can easily remember the password.

Answer (score 0):

As this question doesn't point to any particular implementation technology so I'm just giving you links to get more idea on how this can be done:

[This article explains how this graphical password implementation is done](http://www.usenix.org/events/sec04/tech/full_papers/davis/davis_html/node3.html)

[This is one graphical password project](http://clam.rutgers.edu/~birget/grPssw/)

From here you need to think about the technology to choose to implement this and design as well.